# TSQL Format SSN/TIN (SQL Server 2016+)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to format **US SSN/TIN** strings with dashes when they appear to be valid
(where valid = 9 digits) and otherwise return what is in the field (with leading 0s).

`123456789` should format to `123-45-6789`
and `3456789` formats to `003-45-6789`

Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work?

```
Declare @TaxIDNum VarChar(11)
Set @TaxIDNum = '3456789'
Set @TaxIDNum = Right('0000'+@TaxIDNum,9)
Set @TaxIDNum = 
  CASE @TaxIDNum WHEN Len(@TaxIDNum)=9 THEN 
    CASE @TaxIDNum 
    WHEN IsNumeric(@TaxIDNum) 
    THEN Left(@TaxIDNum,3)+'-'+Right(Left(@TaxIDNum,5),2)+'-'+Right(@TaxIDNum,4) 
    ELSE @TaxIDNum END  -- return existing value
  ELSE @TaxIDNum END    -- return existing value
select @TaxIDNum, len(@TaxIDNum) as Length
```

> I get a red squiggly error on the equals in "=9":
> (Error text is: "Incorrect syntax near '='.")

Any solution that both works with a select or set, and solves the problem is welcome.

---

Thanks to @Larnu for mentioning `Set @TaxIDNum=FORMAT(CONVERT(int,@TaxIDNum),'000-00-0000')`

If I had error handling (our SSvr install doesn't) I would use Format.  However if there is bad data, it breaks my query in a way from which I cannot recover.

`Set @TaxIDNum=Replace('123-45-6789','-','')` does avoid errors if the only data problem is that some of the rows are already formatted.

Comment: You have mixed _simple_ and _searched_ [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) syntaxes, hence the complaint. `IsNumeric` doesn't do what you want. You should use [`like`])https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with a suitable pattern, e.g. `'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`, to determine if the string contains only nine numeric characters.

Comment: @HABO Sorry if I'm being thick, but `CASE @TaxIDNum WHEN @TaxIDNum Like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN...` doesn't work for me. Error=" `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Like'.` " are you saying that these type of statements aren't allowed within a case?

Comment: _Simple_ `case`: `case Foo when 0 then 'Zero' when 1 then 'One' else 'More' end`. _Searched_ `case`: `case when Foo = 0 then 'Zero' when Foo = 1 then 'One' else 'More' end`. Pick one or the other, but you can't mix them in _one_ statement: `case Foo when Foo = 0 ...`.

Comment: @HABO I have placed the full code I think you meant at the bottom of the question - did I do something wrong? (it no longer mixes *simple* and *searched*)

Comment: You've hit an fiendish edge case. There is a [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#boolean-data-type) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set." You can't have `case <boolean-expression> when true then ... end`. ...

Comment: ... You can simplify it to `case when @TaxIDNum Like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then Left(@TaxIDNum,3)+'-'+Right(Left(@TaxIDNum,5),2)+'-'+Right(@TaxIDNum,4) else @TaxIDNum end`. You might also want to look at [`SubString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than `Right(Left( ...`.

Comment: Yeah, I know about substring. For short strings I think Right(Left is more maintainable - and only slightly less efficient since I'm applying it in a result set (as opposed to having it in a join or where clause). I will edit the question so future readers don't have an entire book to consume ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why it does not work

From comments by [HABO][1]

> You have mixed ***simple*** and ***searched*** case syntaxes, hence the complaint.
> You should use LIKE ([learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/…](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))
> with a suitable pattern, e.g.
> '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', to determine if the
> string contains only nine numeric characters.

So I tried this, which also didn't work:

```
SET @TaxIDNum =   
  CASE @TaxIDNum Like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  
  WHEN true 
  THEN  …
```

HABO:

> You've hit an fiendish edge case.
> There is a boolean data type (with
> values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on
> one:
> "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot
> be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and
> cannot be returned in a result set."
>
> You can't have **CASE** «boolean-expression» **WHEN** true **THEN** «result» **END**

#### Solution:

Use LIKE leaving the CASE expression empty

```
declare @TaxIDNum VarChar(11)  
set @TaxIDNum='3456789'  
set @TaxIDNum=right('0000'+@TaxIDNum,9)  
select @TaxIDNum  
SET @TaxIDNum = CASE 
  WHEN @TaxIDNum Like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  
  THEN Left(@TaxIDNum,3)+'-'+SubString(@TaxIDNum,4,2)+'-'+Right(@TaxIDNum,4)  
  ELSE @TaxIDNum END  
select @TaxIDNum
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you could use `FORMAT`:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(int,@TaxIDNum),'000-00-0000');
```

Comment: Thank you!  The problem is that my field isn't numeric, it is text - format works great for numbers but fails (and not gracefully) if the data is dirty. I will add that to my question - thanks again for the answer!

Comment: This is why there is a `CONVERT` there, @J.ChrisCompton , to convert the value to a numerical value first so that `FORMAT` works.